# Private data members are inaccessible to friend function

Tags: c++, class, operators

I'm trying to write overloaded insertion and exertion operators but the functions aren't able to access the private members of the class Money.I have "include namespace std;" and "#include " but it won't let me access the private members (dollars and cents).

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &osObject, Money &right)
{
    osObject << "Amount of money: $" << right.dollars << ".";
    osObject << right.cents;

    return osObject;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &isObject, Money &right)
{
    isObject >> right.dollars;
    isObject.ignore();
    getline(isObject, right.cents;

    return isObject;
}`
```

Header file:

```
#pragma once
class Money{
    // Friends
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream, Money);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream, Money);
private:
    int dollars;
    int cents;
    void simplify();
//Some other stuff...
```

I'm getting errors such as:
syntax error: missing ';' before '&'
'ostream' : 'friend' not permitted on date declarations
missing type specifier- int assumed. C++ does not support default-int

Comment: The signatures of the function declarations and definitions have to match.

Comment: I also assume `getline(isObject, right.cents;` is just a typo...

Answer (score 3):

Your function definition is

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &osObject, Money &right)
```

Your prototype is

```
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream, Money);
```

These are not the same because the first takes an ostream reference argument, and the second uses a plain ostream object. You need to make these match:

```
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, Money &);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a stupid mistake on my part, but it still gives me "inaccessible" error. I added "using namespace std" to my header file which solved the problem with my ostream operator but it's still unable to access the istream-- and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**juanchopanza** already gave the answer in his comment. Just in case you want to see it on  action:

```
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream&, Money);
friend istream & operator>>(istream&, Money);
```

reference signs are missing from the operator arguments ostream and istream.

Comment: The second parameter is also a reference in the OP's function definitions.